# What is the special term for a type of debate where no side would ever agree to the other side?

Tags: terminology

I have been curious if there is a term specifically used to describe the kind of debates where both sides would never accept the other's arguments, and there can never be a consensus.

Especially looking at the kind of debates popular these days in comment sections on social media.

Comment: Looking for a more specialized word, venting may be applicable outside of a debate as well.

Comment: Yeah that is fair

Comment: A specific word should exist for that, or there needs to be. Sort of like "filibuster" is to a parliamentary situation?

Comment: That’s pretty much the distinction between debate and discussion.

Comment: In the context of formal debate, it's pretty much taken for granted that neither side's ***proponents*** will change their minds, so I think perhaps we could discard that aspect of the situation and just say there are ***polarising*** debates (where anyone *listening* to the debate starts and/or ends up being very strongly in favour of one side or the other, there being little scope for establishing a "middle ground").

Comment: In most debates, one side is never going to accept the other side's arguments. I think what you are seeing in social media is not any sort of debate at all, because there are no ground rules. These are just people yelling at each other.

Comment: I've heard "stalemate" used of these situations, but it doesn't necessarily imply a vast difference or vicious social-media-style arguments, and can refer to a very minor debate over trivialities that can't be solved.

Comment: A never-ending dispute. The two sides are **at loggerheads**.

Comment: Especially if the lack of agreement means that things can't get done, this can be called a [deadlock](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deadlock).